# What are the Find and Replace Symbols/Logic in Eclipse IDE for Java Developers 2020-09?

Tags: java, eclipse

What are the Find and Replace Symbols/Logic in Eclipse IDE for Java Developers 2020-09?
I am using the Java programming language.
I want to change certain variable identifiers all at once "replace all", but I need to know how to type what I want to happen in the "Find" box.
I have been trying to find the symbols, but cannot find any material showing or explaining them all.

Comment: "Refactor > Rename..." will rename variables, methods, classes, etc.

Answer (score 0):

select text to be changed,  use short cut  `Alt` + `Shift` + `r`
this will allow you to edit all occurences of text , once changed press enter

Example: you want to rename variable `validInput` to `input` and its all occurences, above command will rename variable and wherever it is used

Comment: Thank you, but I am more looking for a list of the symbols such as things like "!"=not,
(<!r>) = replace all but not the letter "r"

I beleive it looks something like this those symbols, is there a comprehensive list of them somewhere? there has to be.